# Повторение тегов h1, h2

Tags: html, оптимизация

Относительно оптимизации сайта можно ли повторять теги `h1-h6`, но с другим содержимым.

```
<h1>Футбол</h1>
<h1>Баскетбол</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще считается, что нельзя более одного h1. Остальных заголовков может быть несколько.

После появления `<section>` в пятом htmle это ограничение ослаблено.

Answer (score 1):

В доктайпе html5 - можно

В html4 - один тег `Н1` на странице, остальные по вложенности блоков

Answer (score 0):

Желаю вам так же погуглить статей по запросам типа: **заголовки расстановка html**. Благо, тысячи их :). После прочтения нескольки хорошо складывается общее представление.

Еще рекомендую смотреть на валидатор. Подскажет вам в виде warning`ов, если вы порядок заголовков, например, нарушили.